# Entity Framework Assoications - Code First Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, associations, one-to-many, one-to-one

Bit of trouble trying to understand and configure a few relationships. Here are my requirements:

I have a one-to-one relationship, where the principle entity has a navigation property defined in its class, but the dependent does not. Neither entity can exist without the other - how do I specify this relationship in an EntityConfiguration file?

Here are the classes:
**EDIT** (removed PropertyId from PropertyDetail - Property is now the Dependent)

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyDetail : EntityBase
{
}

public class Property : EntityBase
{
  public int PropertyDetail { get; set; }

  public PropertyDetail PropertyDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Is it more, or does Entity Framework require a Navigation property on both ends for a one-to-one relationship where both are required?

Furthermore, how do I properly specify a one-to-many relationship where the principle has no knowledge of the relationship - meanwhile, the dependent entity contains a collection of the principle? Relationship is Optional on both ends.

```
public class Plaintiff : EntityBase
{
}

public class PlaintiffAttorney: EntityBase
{
  public List<Plaintiff> PlaintiffList { get; set; }
}
```

Again, configurations are done within EntityConfiguration files. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: There are a couple of inconsistencies within your code, like ``PropertyDetail`` having a ``PropertyId`` and inheriting from ``EntityBase`` that already has an ``Id`` property.

Comment: Should I drop PropertyId for PropertyDetail, and leave its inherited Id as its primary key and foreign key in Property?

Comment: I would just drop PropertyId and inherit from EntityBase, despite I'm not liking this approach.

Comment: Okay! So I decided to switch Property as the dependent - it will have a foreign key and a navigation property to a PropertyDetail.

How do I configure this relationship - with a constraint on the Foreign Key field in the Property table?

Comment: Can you give me an example - detailing your approach and why? If its not too much trouble.

Comment: I wouldn't create a base class just to inherit an Id property. If not done right, it would only make EF interpret it as TPH inheritance, creating one single table for all your entities. Also, your change would make the relationship become one-to-many.

Comment: My abstract base class contains other required properties - and I avoided EF inheritance by leaving out the MapInheritance() in my various EntityConfiguration files. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a one-to-one relationship, go to the EntityConfiguration class of the principal entity and write this:

```
HasRequired(p => p.PropertyDetail).WithRequiredDependent();
```

As for the one-to-many relationship, you can go to the dependent entity's config class and do this:

```
HasOptional(d => d.PlaintiffList).WithMany();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I do not need the dependent (PropertyDetail) entity to possess a navigation property pointing to a Property? And no configuration is needed in the Property EntityConfiguration class?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can't believe it was that simple, lol.